# Array merge and removal of duplicate values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this foreach loop that outputs the below array, and I'm having a senior moment, I need it to return one array with no duplicate values, and I just can't it right.

```
foreach ( $post_groups as $post_group => $id ) {
    group = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE ID = %d", $id), ARRAY_A);
    $groups[$group['group_name']] = $group['group_name'] = unserialize( $group['group_users'] );
}
```

output:

```
array(2) {
    ["Registered Users"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["Admin Users"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Use 1 select statement with IN. It will be much faster than N statements being executed in foreach

Comment: Question is not clear: you want simply obtain id (like in Tom Wright example) or you want preserve the groups (Registered Users, Admin Users, etc...). In this case, what is the rule? That is, what group key you want preserve in conflict cases? And how many groups they are?

Comment: Tom's answer is exactly what I wanted, all i need to do now is do the arrays for the array merge dynamically as there can be loads of groups not just the two in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following is what you're after. Simply merge the arrays together and then ensure the result is unique.

```
$userIds = [
    'Registered Users' => array(1,2,3),
    'Admin Users' => array(3,4,5),
];

$allUserIds = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $userIds));

var_dump($userIds);
/*
array(2) {
  ["Registered Users"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
  ["Admin Users"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    [1]=>
    int(4)
    [2]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
*/

var_dump($allUserIds);
/*
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(4)
  [5]=>
  int(5)
}
*/
```

Comment: sorry one thing I forgot is that the groups are dynamic and can be loads of them. so I just need to get the array merge bit to work now for that.
I'm so tried at the moment, that my brain won't properly and i can't even figure that bit out, duh

Comment: I have updated my answer so it will work with any amount of groups.

Answer (score -1):

**Use to php functions : `array_unique(array_merge())`**

test code:

```
$userIds = array('RegisteredUsers' => array('A','a','b','B'),'AdminUsers' => array('C','c','B','d','a'));

$allUserIds = array_unique(array_merge($userIds['RegisteredUsers'],     $userIds['AdminUsers']));
echo "<br><br>";

var_dump($userIds);
var_dump($allUserIds);
```

Comment: Yep, same answer that @TomWright posted 20 minutes ago. You even managed to use the same number of extra spaces inside the code. Looks like you copied it. Well done. :/

Comment: Jest edited err  @ array() and text format only guys ...  K.. Thanks  @trincot

Comment: If you feel there is a tiny error like that, or a format that can be improved, then suggest an edit to that particular answer, or mention it in a comment. To bluntly copy/paste someone's answer and make it your own with some minor changes is really not respectful towards the one who wrote the answer.